# Admin inline with no ForeignKey relation

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-1.11

Is it possible to manually specify the set of related object to show in an inline, where no foreign key relation exists?

```
# Parent
class Diary(models.Model):
    day = models.DateField()
    activities = models.TextField()

# Child
class Sleep(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()

class SleepInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model=Sleep
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        # Return all Sleep objects where start_time and end_time are within Diary.day
        return Sleep.objects.filter(XXX) 

class DiaryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (SleepInline, )
```

I want my `Diary` model admin to display an inline for `Sleep` models that have `start_time` equal to the same day as `Diary.day`. The problem is that the `Sleep` model does not have a `ForeignKey` to `Diary` (instead, the relation is implicit by the use of dates).

Using the above, Django immediately complains that

```
<class 'records.admin.SleepInline'>: (admin.E202) 'records.Sleep' has no ForeignKey to 'records.Diary'.
```

How can I show the relevant `Sleep` instances as inlines on the `Diary` admin page?

Comment: have you tried using property?

Comment: There **is** a relation. You're just denying it. Once you're over your denial, add a ManyToManyField on either side.

Comment: @Melvyn I don't think it's a good idea to add redundant DB columns that I have to manually keep in sync as a workaround for the way Django presents its admin. Maybe there is a way I can fake it with a property or similar without touching the schema?

Comment: What's this manually keep in sync you're talking about? Also, are these your real models? Cause a) you mark Diary as parent of Sleep and your code contradicts it and b) in real world terms, I don't get the relation between diary and sleep.

Comment: @Melvyn This is just an example: `Diary` logs what the user does in a day, and `Sleep` tracks when the user sleeps. Logically a "Diary entry" for a single day also contains (a list of) `Sleep` objects, but I don't want to actually add a `ForeignKey` `Sleep.diary` because then I have to keep it in sync with `start_time` and `end_time` manually - i.e. override `Sleep.save()` to point to the correct `Diary` object based on `start_time` and `end_time` entered by the user. I don't want to change my schema for the sole purpose of making that inbuilt admin work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me start by showing you the drawbacks of your logic:

- When adding a foreign key, there are 2 operations, that are uncommon that require adjusting the relation: creating a new sleep object and updating the times on the sleep object.
- When not using a foreign key, each time a diary is requested the lookup for the corresponding Sleep object(s) needs to be done. I'm assuming reading diaries is much more common then alterations of sleep objects, as it will be in most projects out there.

The additional drawback as you've noticed, is that you cannot use relational features. InlineAdmin is a relational feature, so as much as you say "making the admin work", it is really that you demand a hammer to unscrew a bolt.

But...the admin makes use of ModelForm. So if you construct the form with a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/) (which cannot be a an inline formset for the same reason) and handle saving that formset yourself, it should be possible. The whole point of InlineFormset and InlineAdmin is to make generation of formsets from related models easier and for that it needs to know the relation.

And finally, you can [add urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites) and build a custom page, and when extending the admin/base.html template, you will have access to the layout and javascript components.

Answer (score 8):

There is no getting around the fact that Django admin inlines are built around `ForeignKey` fields (or `ManyToManyField`, `OneToOneField`).  However, if I understand your goal, it's to avoid having to manage "date integrity" between your `Diary.day` and `Sleep.start_time` fields, i.e., the redundancy in a foreign key relation when that relation is really defined by `Diary.day == Sleep.start_time.date()`

A Django `ForiegnKey` field has a [to_field property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) that allows the FK to index a column besides `id`. However, as you have a `DateTimeField` in `Sleep` and a `DateField` in `Diary`, we'll need to split that `DateTimeField` up. Also, a `ForeignKey` has to relate to something unique on the "1" side of the relation. `Diary.day` needs to be set `unique=True`.

In this approach, your models look like

```
from django.db import models

# Parent
class Diary(models.Model):
    day = models.DateField(unique=True)
    activities = models.TextField()

# Child
class Sleep(models.Model):
    diary = models.ForeignKey(Diary, to_field='day', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

and then your `admin.py` is just

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Sleep, Diary

class SleepInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model=Sleep

@admin.register(Diary)
class DiaryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (SleepInline, )
```

Even though `Sleep.start_time` no longer has a date, the Django Admin is quite what you'd expect, and avoids "date redundancy":

[image: Django Admin: Diary]

---

Thinking ahead to a more real (and problematic) use case, say every user can have 1 Diary per day:

```
class Diary(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    day = models.DateField()
    activities = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'day')
```

One would like to write something like

```
class Sleep(models.Model):
    diary = models.ForeignKey(Diary, to_fields=['user', 'day'], on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

However, there's no such feature in Django 1.11, nor can I find any serious discussion of adding that. Certainly composite foreign keys are allowed in Postgres and other SQL DBMS's. I get the impression from the Django source they're keeping their options open: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L621 hints at a future implementation.

Finally, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-composite-foreignkey looks interesting at first, but doesn't create "real" composite foreign keys, nor does it work with Django's admin.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this will work in the date case but won't solve the more general problem of using a custom query instead of a `ForeignKey` relation - is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. This is the most "Django-thonic" way. I did a brief experiment, trying to "fake" the inline foreign key field using various tricks, some undocumented. That approach led to increasingly ugly Django problems to workaround.

I still believe there is a way to achieve what you're looking for (which makes a lot of sense, fwiw). However, I'm pretty sure it would require a custom ORM field inherited from [RelatedField](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L81), and not be a simple queryset in your admin, inline classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, using [nested_admin library](https://django-nested-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

So in `myapp/admin.py`:

```
from nested_admin.nested import NestedStackedInline, NestedModelAdmin

class SleepInline(NestedStackedInline):

    model = Sleep

class DiaryAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):

   inlines = [SleepInline]
```

Comment: I have tried it in a similar case, with the only difference that there is a foreign key relation, but the other way round. Contact has a Foreign key to CaseStudy, but I would like to have the Contact form inside the case study instead of having a choice field and a plus sign for adding a Contact instance. Since I have django-nested-admin and  django-nested-inline installed anyway, I wanted to give it a try, but I got an error complaining about Contact not having a ForeignKey to CaseStudy.